# Evitar campo duplicado de BD PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla en la Base de Datos donde tengo campos repetidos y campos en blanco. Y debo mostrar los resultados sin repeticiones y sin campos vacíos.

He trabajado en el siguiente código, que hasta el momento me lo hace:

```html
for($nombres=array();$row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_fact);$nombres[$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']]=$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']){
    
    if(!$nombres[$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']] && $row['CRAZONSOCIAL'] != '' ){
   ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['CRAZONSOCIAL'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['CFOLIO'] ?></td>
     </tr>
   <?php
    }
   }
```

No tiene problemas excepto porque me sale lo siguiente:

```
> Notice: Undefined index: TELCEL in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: MOVISTAR SA DE CV in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: GLOBOSYSTEM in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: VENDEDOR 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: PROVEEDOR 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: proveedor prueba in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\w_facturas.php on line 37
```

La línea 37 vendría teniendo esto:

```
    if(!$nombres[$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']] && $row['CRAZONSOCIAL'] != '' ){
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo logré resolver, lo dejo por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo.

```html
for($nombres=array();$row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_fact);$nombres[$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']]=$row['CRAZONSOCIAL'])
    $variable = isset($nombres[$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']]) ? $nombres[$row['CRAZONSOCIAL']] : null ;
    if(!$variable && $row['CRAZONSOCIAL'] != '' ){
   ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['CRAZONSOCIAL'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['CRAZONSOCIAL'] ?></td>
     </tr>
   <?php
    }
   }
```

Comment: Deberías añadir una pequeña de qué cambiaste y por qué funcionó. Tal y como está ahora la respuesta es difícil de leer y no es fácil ver qué es lo que hiciste